# Unable to use std:: counting_semaphore in Visual Studio 2019 and 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, semaphore, binary-semaphore

So I am trying to use counting_semaphore in visual studio 2019 and 2022 but all I get is " std has no member counting_semaphore".

I tried it in visual studio 2019 after adding the clang 11 in individual components but I still get the same error. Then I was like ok it doesn't support C++20. So I thought maybe that's why it doesn't work.

Then I saw Vs2022 Preview supports C++20. So I installed it, included  and still I cant do       "std::counting_semaphore<5> slots(5);"  as it says std doesn't have a member called counting semaphore.

I also installed clang12 in the individual components in 2022 preview installer and still I didn't get it to work.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I see examples online:

https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/semaphores-in-c-20
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore

telling how to use it, but when I put the code in vs it just doesn't work.

I can do "view code" on #include  and it shows implementation of counting_semaphore and yet I cant use it!!!

Kindly someone please clarify what I am doing wrong!!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*Then I saw Vs2022 Preview supports C++20*" - where? Are you certain that the source claimed that VS2022 Preview supports **the entire** C++20? That is very highly unlikely. And by "*doesn't work*", do you mean that it actually doesn't compile or you just have a false-positive error in your editor?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20

Comment: @Fureeish Says so on https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/vs2022/ site in C++20  Support. But it doesnt say what all features are supported, but does say latest toolchain supported. When I say it doesnt work I mean I get std has no member counting_semaphore.

Comment: @Kevin Yes I saw that but that really doesn't help as I have clang11 installed and using the visual studio version mentioned in it for using counting_semaphore.

Comment: "*When I say it doesnt work I mean I get std has no member counting_semaphore.*" - but do you get that **in the editor** (as shown on the screenshot + potentially when you hover your mose over it) or do you **actually get a compiler error when *compiling the code despite the visual indicator for an error***?

Comment: @Fureeish I get a compiler error as well. I have included screenshot of the build errors as well.

Comment: Which preview version do you have. Visual Studio 2022, version 17.0.0.0, preview 2.1 does have `counting_semaphore`.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes I am running the same...  but I am having the above issue using it.

Comment: @SiddharthShekar I was assuming that C++ Language Standard option was well known...

Comment: @Phil1970 I assumed that the latest version of VS always defaulted to latest version of C++. Guess it always defaults to C++14. Didn't know that!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you have set the c++ language standard?

`Property -> General -> C++ Language Standard -> /std: c++ latest`

[image]

I could build successfully in visual studio 2022 preview 17.0.0 preview 2.0.

[image]

And I could also build successfully in visual studio 2019.

[image]

Comment: @SiddharthShekar 
We are appreciate that you are satisfied with the help we provide. If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers.

Comment: @SiddharthShekar You could click the "check" in front of the answer.